# pushing values in array in hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I had a following jquery code where i need to push values in a hidden field using comma if there are multiple items added.

i am using this code for pushing values but i am confused where and how do i add value in the hidden field so i can use the chosen value

jquery code

```
function initializeAutocomplete(obj){
    obj.autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var values = [];
            for(var x = 0;x < predifined_cources.length;x++){
                if(predifined_cources[x].text.indexOf(request.term)>-1)
                    values.push({"label":predifined_cources[x].text, "value":predifined_cources[x].id+"~YES"}); 
            }
            if(values.length==0){
                $.post("customers.cfm",{"term":request.term})
                .done(function(data){
                    try{
                        var obj = $.parseJSON(data),
                        values = [];
                        for(var x = 0; x < obj.length; x++){
                            values.push({"label":obj[x].text, "value":obj[x].id});
                        }
                        response(values);
                    }catch(e){
                    }
                })
                .fail(function(e){
                });
            }
            else
                response(values);
        },
        change: function(event, ui) {
            if (!ui.item) {
                $(this).next().val('');
            } 
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).next().val(ui.item.value);
            ui.item.value = ui.item.label;
        }
    });
}
initializeAutocomplete($('[selectCustomer]').first());
```

html code:

```
<input selectCustomer name="customer_name" class="form-control" id="customer_name_select" value="" placeholder="Select Customer..." data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Choose Customer"/>
                                <input type="hidden" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the loop is complete that creates the array you would convert the array to string and set the value of the field

You could use JSON to keep array structure

```
$('#customer_name_select').val( JSON.stringify(array));
```

Or for comma separated string use `Array.prototype.join()`

```
$('#customer_name_select').val( array.join());
```

Comment: but where i should add this, i want to add them to hidden field rather than the `customer_name_select `. i have given the hidden field id as `customer_name_hidden`

Comment: give hidden field an ID and use that instead of the select one

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery `data`-function.  It allows you to add objects to DOM - elements without having to convert them manually to a string. It is only sufficient if you need the data only on client - side.